# Returning ResponseEntity<CustomApiResponse> in Spring Boot Controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, http, spring-mvc

I use the following custom `ApiResponse` class to return data from my Spring Boot app Controllers:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApiResponse<T> {

    private Long timestamp;
    private final String message;
    private final T data;

    public ApiResponse(Long timestamp, String message) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.message = message;
        this.data = null;
    }
}
```

And use it in the Controller methods as shown below:

```
@GetMapping
ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Page<PostDTO>>> findAll() {
    final Page<PostDTO> response = postService.findAll();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse<>(Instant.now(clock).toEpochMilli(), "Success", response));
}
```

By this approach, I format my response as shown below by adding message ("Success, etc.), a timestamp and wrap response in data. Here is the difference by using this `ApiResponse`:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1678124639846,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": {
```

At this point, I am wondering i it wrong to use this kind of custom response class and wrap it inside `ResponseEntity` when returning response from Controller? Could you share your feedbacks please?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your technique.

Comment: @DwB Thanks a lot for sharing your opinions. Then, I think I should use this technique as `ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<List<PostDTO>>>` instead of `ResponseEntity<List<PostDTO>>`,  right?

Comment: That is reasonable.  There is a log of flexibility in what you return from a handler method.  I prefer `ResponseEntity`, but others do not.

Comment: Actually I compared using `ApiResponse` or not in my previous comment. Because, in both cases, I use ``ResponseEntity`, but only one of them is using  `ApiResponse`. Any idea?